# Iterate over a list in Frida

Tags: java, android, mobile, frida

I am trying to figure out how to read a public `unmodifiableList` field of a Java class with Frida.
Here is the class I have:

```java
public final class MyClass {
   public final String myString;
   public final List myList;

   public MyClass() {
       this.myString = "Hello!";
       this.myList = Collections.unmodifiableList({ "this_is_a_string" });
   }
}
```

and here is the JS Frida code I am using to extract the two fields:

```js
Java.perform(function() {
    function onField(instance) {
        const fields = instance.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            const value = fields[i].get(instance);
            if(fields[i].getName() == "myString") {
                // This correctly prints "Hello!".
                console.log("myString: " + value);
            } else if(fields[i].getName() == "myList") {
                for(var j = 0; j < value.length; i++) {
                    // This prints out a blank line, as opposed to "this_is_a_string".
                    console.log(value[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Java.choose("com.myapp.MyClass", { onField: onField, onComplete: function() {} })
});
```

The problem is that I cannot access any methods or fields of the unmodifiableList (size() and indexing included.). How can I read from this list?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved with the usage of `Java.cast`.

```js
// ...
var list = Java.cast(value, Java.use("java.util.List"));
```